# Clear site data of safari programmatically

Tags: reactjs, safari, cachestorage

I'm implementing a function in my React web app, that allows the user to clear cache storage/site data from Safari or Chrome. In Windows Chrome, I can clear it by clearing cache storage. How to do it in Safari on iPad?